# tqdm progress bar with estimated duration

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I want to use TQDM to show a progress bar for a process. I know roughly how long this process will take (based on an empirical model I have fit).

The `tqdm()` `length` parameter makes it easy to set a progress bar's length based on a known iterable size, but I can't see a way to do the same thing when you know a duration, not a size.

Comment: In your process are you iterating over an iterable?

Comment: Nope! Hence the difficulty.

Comment: Since Python reads line-after-line, there should be intervals in *your long process* to update the progress bar. It is simple when we do iteration. If your process doesn't have definite intervals, you cannot use tqdm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `tqdm` to display a progress bar at all, you need to make your long-running process a generator that `yield`s periodically so that the progress bar can be updated in the interim.

With the periodic `yield` implemented, you can then create a generator that iterates over the generator that is your long-running process while also iterating over a separate `tqdm` object according to the number of seconds elapsed. The separate `tqdm` object should be created over an indefinitely repeating iterator (such as `itertools.cycle(' ')`) with the `total` argument specified with the number of seconds your long-running process is expected to run, so that the number of seconds elapsed will be scaled properly when the progress bar is displayed.

The example below shows you such a generator over a long-running process that takes a total of 9 seconds to run, while `yield`ing updates in the interim with 2, 4 and 3-second intervals:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import time, sleep
from itertools import cycle

def tqdm_duration(iterable, duration):
    progress_bar = iter(tqdm(cycle(' '), total=duration, mininterval=0))
    next(progress_bar)
    last_progress = 0
    start_time = time()
    for _ in iterable:
        progress = int(time() - start_time)
        for _ in range(last_progress, progress):
            next(progress_bar)
        last_progress = progress
        yield

def nine_second_work(): # your long-running process, taking 9 seconds in this example
    for interval in 2, 4, 3: # 2 + 4 + 3 == 9
        sleep(interval) # actual work is done here
        yield # this gives a chance for tqdm to update the progress bar

for _ in tqdm_duration(nine_second_work(), 9):
    pass
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DapperAustereFrontpage

Comment: You seem unaware of [manual](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#manual) usage...

Comment: Also, you want a "repeating" iterator and choose `cycle` over `repeat`? :-)